# Slackでメッセージが届くたびにスプレッドシートに書き出していく

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

#### 今回実装したいもの

slackである人がメッセージを送ったり、自分が投稿するたびに投稿した時間と内容をスプレッドシートに書き出していきたい

#### 今回悩んでいること・お聞きしたいこと

以下のリンクを参考に(というか必要箇所以外写しました)GASを実行したところ、自分の勤怠報告?がループしてしまいます。for文などを使用していないのに処理が止まらない理由が分からないこと

上記のものを実装するために必要なコードは以下のもので足りるのか。

まだまだ未熟で質問すら下手で申し訳ありませんが、お力添えいただけますと恐縮です。どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

参考にしたリンク：
[【GASで作るslack bot】スプレッドシートと連携してシフト管理botを作る（予定の入力と確認通知）](https://qiita.com/tacos_salad/items/9fe997a34cebc8fcef39)

以下コードです。

```
function doPost(e) {
/*   //test（Slackからjson形式で以下のようにデータが送られてくる（一部分）。GAS上で実行テストを行う際にはこの部分のコメントアウトを外して実行してください。）
  e = {
    parameter : {
      user_name : "hoge_hoge",
      text : "att_entry yes 23:45",
    }
  }
*/
  var data = e.parameter.text // textを取得
  var username = e.parameter.user_name // user_nameを取得
  data = username + ' ' + data // dataの結合（[user_name] [yes or no] [time]）
  data = data.split(' ') // dataをスペース区切りで分割
  recordData(data);
}

// botからSlackへの投稿
function postSlack(text){
  var url = "自分のwebhookのURL";
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    "headers": {"Content-type": "application/json"},
    "payload" : '{"text":"' + text + '"}'
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}

// Spreadsheetへの入力
function recordData (data) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('自分のスプシID');
  var recordsheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('シート1');  
  var lastrow = recordsheet.getLastRow();
  var recordrow = lastrow + 1;
  var date = new Date();
  var formatdate = Utilities.formatDate(date, 'Asia/Tokyo', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');

  // セルを指定してdataを入力
  recordsheet.getRange("A" + recordrow).setValue(formatdate);
  recordsheet.getRange("B" + recordrow).setValue(data[0]);
  recordsheet.getRange("C" + recordrow).setValue(data[1]);
  recordsheet.getRange("D" + recordrow).setValue(data[2]);
  recordsheet.getRange("E" + recordrow).setValue(data[3]);

  // 入力完了をSlackへ通知
  postSlack(data[0] + "さんの勤務予定を入力しました\n" + "勤務予定時間：" + data[3]);
}
```

Comment: 参考記事の作成者に[回答](https://qiita.com/tacos_salad/items/9fe997a34cebc8fcef39#comment-ce13f434fa01e8df57c8)していただけそうですので一旦そちらを待ったほうがいいかなと思います。またこの質問はマルチポストの部類になるかと思います。念のためこのサイトのマルチポストの注意点もご覧ください「[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/)」

Comment: ご連絡下さりありがとうございます。解決したのですが、クローズする際は投稿を消してしまっても良いのでしょうか？？お聞きすることではないかもしれませんが、ご返信いただけますと恐縮です。

Comment: 同じ課題に取り組む人たちのために、このサイトでは自己回答を奨励しています。ご自身で解決に至った方法と結論をぜひ書いてみてください。[自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そもそも上記のものはIncomingWebhookを使っているものなので、
Outgoing　Webhookを使用することで解決しました。
以下のようにスプレッドシート取得と、トークンを記述し、入力をしていくことができるようです！

```
function doPost(e) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(ここにシート名);
  const token = トークン
}
```